# JsTree how to get IDs of group node

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jstree

I want to get IDs of all child, Surface nodes, and a higher level.
See the image below

[image]

When i click on `C1` node :

1 - I want the IDs of all the lower level nodes contains : D1 , D2

2 - I want the IDs of node that is a higher direct level : B2

3 - And i want the IDs of all IDs of straight level : C2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsTree's API provides with functions to identify and traverse between nodes. Here's a small script you could use to identify child, parent(direct level) & sibling nodes(straight level).

```
$('#jstree').bind('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var tree = $('#jstree').jstree(true),
        parentNode = tree.get_node(data.node.parent),
        aChildren = data.node.children,
        aSiblings = [];

        parentNode.children.forEach(function(c){
            if(c !== data.node.id) aSiblings.push(c);
        });

        console.log("1.)" + JSON.stringify(aChildren));
        console.log("2.)" + JSON.stringify(parentNode.id));
        console.log("3.)" + JSON.stringify(aSiblings));
});
```